# Dropdown's, dropbtn's and display issues

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so I've only recently started dabbling with dropdown lists and button etc. and I've managed to make 3 lists to run from a fixed position navigation bar. Each list I have made successfully works, but never all at the same time in the same way, at the point of this question, I have the first and last lists working how I would like, but the 2nd list, despite having the same script (aside from id's), isn't displaying like the other two. Any help to fix my issue would be appreciated.

(BEAR IN MIND, FUNCTION 3 IS THE ISSUE FOR LIST NO.2)
(using Dreamweaver CC 2017)

```js
function myFunction1() {
  document.getElementById("myFruit").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown =
      document.getElementById("myFruit");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("myScripts").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown =
      document.getElementById("myScripts");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}

function myFunction3() {
  document.getElementById("posters").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(e) {
  if (!e.target.matches('dropbtn')) {
    var myDropdown =
      document.getElementById("posters");
    if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/assignment.css" media="screen" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="navigation">
            <div class="dropdown">
               <div class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction1()">
                  <h4>Task 1</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="dropdown-content" id="myFruit">
                  <a href="#" target="_self">DragonFruit</a>
                  <a href="#" target="_self">Apricot</a>
                  <a href="#" target="_self">Lemon</a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
               <div class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction3()">
                  <h4>Task 2</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="dropdown-content" id="posters">
                  <a href="#" target="_self">banana</a>
                  <a href="#" target="_self">apple</a>
                  <a href="#" target="_self">pear</a>
                  <a href="#" target="_self">orange</a>
                  <a href="#" target="_self">strawberry</a>
                  <a href="#" target="_self">Grape</a>
                  <a href="#" target="_self">peach</a>
                  <a href="#" target="_self">lime</a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
               <div class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction2()">
                  <h4>Task3</h4>
                  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myScripts">
                     <a href="#" target="_self">little</a>
                     <a href="#" target="_self">men</a>
                     <a href="#" target="_self">dont</a>
                     <a href="#" target="_self">worry</a>
                     <a href="#" target="_self">about</a>
                     <a href="#" target="_self">what</a>
                     <a href="#" target="_self">the</a>
                     <a href="#" target="_self">links</a>
                     <a href="#" target="_self">display</a>
                     <a href="#" target="_self">am</a>
                     <a href="#" target="_self">I</a>
                     <a href="#" target="_self">Right</a>
                     <a href="#" target="_self">there</a>
                     <a href="#" target="_self">boys?</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add Images showcasing the difference in their visuals?

Comment: @anu sure     https://imgur.com/a/4VcxM     3 images relative to different views and programs are at this URL, (i realised that without the CSS, the coding above doesn't do a lot)

Answer (score 0):

So uh, I fixed it with help from a couple friends.
Instead of using scripts to enable hovering or clicking and displaying of links, I was sent a html/css combination and I copied one single piece of code from the friends css.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
```

}

And after deleting all the functions and id's etc. it worked as i had originally had intended. *I can't believe that this was so simple to fix,*

**facepalm**